# Map on Observable Stream Not Calling Function

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have an array of Observables that I create by pushing HTTP requests into an Observable array.

Once these requests are done, I `forkJoin` the collection of Observables and then from there, I'd like to then loop over this collection, perform some function on each item, and then finally, execute one last method.

I have something similar to this:

```
// Firstly, get all of the items
private _getItems(): Observable<MyItems[]> {
    let items: Observable<MyItems>[] = [];

    Object.keys(this._items).map(item => {
        items.push(this.service.getItemState(item))
    });

    return Observable.forkJoin(items);
}
```

---

```
// Secondly, loop through items and perform function
this._getItems()
    .map(items => items.map(item => {
        this._setState(item);
    }))
    // Finally, do my last method
    .subscribe(() => {
        this._prepareItems();
    });
}
```

I'm not sure of why, but `this._setState(item)` is never being called. Is this the right way to go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: try to change push sentence to `items.push(this.service.getItemState(item).map((res)=> res));`

Answer (score 1):

At first forkJoin is a good choice since it waits for all of your http-requests to complete. But im not sure if your forEach on the object is working? Wouldn't it be like this:

```
Object.keys(this._items).map((key, index) => {
     items.push(this.service.getItemState(this._items[key]))
});
```

On your second example you create a new observable by using map with the forkJoin observable as source. You use `map` but dont map anything so instead use `tap()`(was called `do()` on before RxJS 5.5)

I would highly recommend you to insert a console.log on nearly each line of your code and see if its working correctly. Is the forEach on object working? Is _getItems() every emitting something? (use do/tap for console.log)

Btw you should not call everything "item". `this._setState(item);` is probably more something like `this._setState(itemState);` isnt it?

Comment: Also will be better to replace `Object.keys(this._items).map((key, index)`  => `Object.keys(this._items).forEach((key, index)`. It doesn't editing `_items`

Answer (score 0):

This should work, regardless of the version of Angular / RxJS that you are using.

```js
// Your code that isn't working:
/*// Firstly, get all of the items
private _getItems(): Observable<MyItems[]> {
  let items: Observable<MyItems>[] = [];

  Object.keys(this._items).map(item => {
    items.push(this.service.getItemState(item))
  });

  return Observable.forkJoin(items);
}

// Secondly, loop through items and perform function
this._getItems()
    .map(items => items.map(item => {
        this._setState(item);
    }))
    // Finally, do my last method
    .subscribe(() => {
        this._prepareItems();
    });
}*/

// Code rewritten (Angular 2-4 / RxJS 2-4):
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

private _getItems(): Observable<MyItems[]> {
  return Observable.forkJoin(
    Object.keys(this._items)
      .map(item => this.service.getItemState(item))
  );
}

this._getItems()
  .map(items => items.map(item => {
    this._setState(item);
    return item;
  }))
  .subscribe(
    item => this._prepareItems(),
    err => console.error(err)
  );

// Code rewritten (Angular 5+ / RxJS 5+):
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

private _getItems(): Observable<MyItems[]> {
  return Observable.combineLatest(
    Object.keys(this._items)
      .map(item => this.service.getItemState(item))
  );
}

this._getItems()
  .pipe(
    tap(items => items.map(item => this._setState(item)))
  )
  .subscribe(
    item => this._prepareItems(),
    err => console.error(err)
  );
```